# React native drawer open issue

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to implement a drawer menu in react native and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Here is what I have so far:

```
#App.js
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
    Save: SaveScreen,
    About: AboutScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

#Homescreen.js
     static navigationOptions = {
    // headerTitle instead of title
    drawerLabel: 'Home',
    headerTitle: 

        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: 16}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={()=>{this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}}>
          <Image
            source={require('../../assets/ic-hamburger.png')}
            style={{ width: 20, height: 18 }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Text style={styles.menuTitle}>Menu</Text>
      </View>
  };
```

How come this.props.navigation is undefined here? How do I retrieve it so that the drawer opens when the image is clicked?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using the `navigation` object:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
// headerTitle instead of title
drawerLabel: 'Home',
headerTitle: 

    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: 16}}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}>
      ....
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
});
```